# asp.net entity framework confused

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4

Good day,

My program is giving me so much trouble. It is all of a sudden giving me an error:

Invalid column name 'UserProfile_UserId'.

for this code:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
---> var model = _db.Roles.ToList();    
return View(model);
```

Which makes sense. But the problem is i.m not even using the user profiles class. Im using the Roles class.

Here is my controller:

```
 FSKDb _db = new FSKDb();
    //
    // GET: /Roles/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = _db.Roles.ToList();

        return View(model);
    }
```

and here is my DB Class:

```
namespace Attempt3.Models
{
public class FSKDb : DbContext
{
    public FSKDb() : base("name=DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Roles> Roles { get; set; }   
}
}
```

Roles class:

```
[Table("webpages_Roles")]
public class Roles
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

UserProfile Class

```
   [Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string ClientCode { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Roles> UserRoles { get; set; }
}
```

Im not sure why when i try and find roles in my controller that the EF is trying to look for User Profiles_UserID

It should only look for that if i am looking for a user, not a role. and even so the UserProfile UserId coloumn name is just "UserId"   and not "UserProfile_UserId"

Thanks

Comment: Hey, I copied all code from your question and I haven't got problems. Do you have smth in OnModelCreating  or other fluent api part of EF?

Comment: Second question: your EF code generates one-to-many relationship beetween User and Role (one User have many Roles, one Role have one User). That seems very odd. Maybe you need many-to-many relationship? (one User have many Roles, one Role have many Users). If so, you must add to Roles class collection of UserProfiles.

Comment: Some thing is very weird, it was working for me too and the it started with this error, but it has something to do with my models. I am trying to input roles into the default generated roles table.}}

Comment: I am just making use of the default roles tables. it has another table called Users in roles and that is where you can link up multiple users for a role.

Answer (score 0):

You have one-to-many relationship between `UserProfile` and `Roles`. So each Role is associated with one user and therefore UserProfile_ID is stored in Roles table. To build many-to-many relationship you must do:

1. Specify in class `UserProfile` that it have many `Roles` - done by you
2. Specify in class `Role` that it have many UserProfiles:

   ```
   [Table("webpages_Roles")]
   public class Roles
   {
       [Key]
       [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
       public int RoleId { get; set; }
       public string RoleName { get; set; }
       public string Description { get; set; }
       public ICollection<UserProfile> Users { get; set; }
   }
   ```

Yeah, that's all. Now EF will generate third table named `UserProfileRoles` and will make hidden one-to-many relationships between `UserProfile` and `UserProfileRoles`, between `Role` and `UserProfileRoles`. If you want to change table name, in your class of context you must override `OnModelCreating` and use fluent api to configure mapping of classes to tables:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder
        .Entity<UserProfile>()
        .HasMany<Roles>(u => u.UserRoles)
        .WithMany(u => u.Users)
        .Map(m => {
            m.ToTable("_myOwnMapTable_UserProfile__Roles");
        });

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Links:

1. [Get Started with Entity Framework (EF)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/data/ee712907)
2. [Configuring/Mapping Properties and Types with the Fluent API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/data/jj591617)
3. [Configuring Relationships with the Fluent API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/data/jj591620)